# Padding generated by slider

Tags: jquery, css

I have installed a slider on a [website](http://www.startupsandfinance.com/cise4/cise_blue). The sliders code is producing a padding on top which is different for different browsers. Inspite of trying to fix up the error I am unable to do it. Please help out.

Here is the code,

```
<div class="main-slider-content" style="width:960px; height:340px;">
                <ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
                    <li>
                            <img src="images/thumbl_980x340.png" title="Newsflash 2" >           
                          <div class="slider-description"><div class="description-wrapper">
                            <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 1" href="#Category-1">/ Newsflash 1 /</a> <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 1</h4>
                            <p>The one thing about a Web site, it always changes! Joomla! makes it easy to add Articles, content,...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                         </div></div>
                    </li> 
                   <li>
                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_002.png" title="Newsflash 1" >           
                         <div class="slider-description"><div class="description-wrapper">
                           <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 2" href="#Category-2">/ Newsflash 2 /</a>  <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 2</h4>
                            <p>Joomla! makes it easy to launch a Web site of any kind. Whether you want a brochure site or you are...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                         </div></div>
                  </li> 
                   <li>
                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_003.png" title="Newsflash 3" >            
                        <div class="slider-description"><div class="description-wrapper">
                          <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 3" href="#Category-3">/ Newsflash 3 /</a>   <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 3</h4>
                            <p>With a library of thousands of free Extensions, you can add what you need as your site grows. Don't...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>

                        </div></div>
                  </li> 
                    <li>
                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_004.png" title="Newsflash 5" >            
                        <div class="slider-description"><div class="description-wrapper">
                          <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 4" href="#Category-4">/ Newsflash 4 /</a>   <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 4</h4>
                            <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                        </div></div>
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_005.png" title="Newsflash 5" >            
                        <div class="slider-description"><div class="description-wrapper">
                           <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 5" href="#">/ Newsflash 5 /</a>    <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                           <h4>Content of Newsflash 5</h4>
                            <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                      </div></div>
                    </li> 
                    <li>

                      <img src="images/thumbl_980x340_006.png" title="Newsflash 5" >            
                        <div class="slider-description"><div class="description-wrapper">
                          <div class="slider-meta"><a target="_parent" title="Newsflash 6" href="#">/ Newsflash 6 /</a> <i> — Monday, February 15, 2010 12:42</i></div>
                            <h4>Content of Newsflash 6</h4>
                            <p>Joomla! 1.5 - 'Experience the Freedom'!. It has never been easier to create your own dynamic Web...
                            <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more </a>
                            </p>
                        </div> </div>
                    </li> 

      </ul>     
            </div>
           <!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sliders-wrap-inner li img { width: 960px; max-width:960px }
```

Your images are too big for the container which is causing some wrapping type issues.